# receive and store SMS to a specific application

Tags: android, sms, messaging, sendmessage

i need some help in starting off my project. i would like to know if it is possible for android to receive a SMS to the application im creating. ok..here is the senario:

i have to create a classroom voting application where the teacher using android phone is able to receive SMS from the student as a form of voting and store it inside the app. it must show an overview of how many students voted for the correct answer.

is it possible to do? and can other OS platform send message to the android app and its not shown inside the native messaging app and only in the app im developing?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible in android to receive any incoming SMS i have used the following link for my reference.

http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/15/android-listen-for-incoming-sms-messages/
and yes

Comment: thank you but im not able to download the zip file..its broken.. any other solutions for me to look at ?